# how to echo image alt in wordpress attachment page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a piece of code for wordpress attachment page

```
$image_size = apply_filters( 'wporg_attachment_size', 'large' );
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID(), $image_size );
```

it woks fine and show the image with everything including Alt,
but I want to show attachment ALT text below the image.
what should I use?
like this image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display just the alt text below your image seperately by getting the alt text from the post within the DB.

```
<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use wp_get_attachment_image_url with img tag.

```
<img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url(get_the_ID(), $image_size); ?>" alt="Text" />
```